# undefined method `find_in_batches' for #<PG::Result - rpush, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to fetch the records from rpush_notifications table which has error_code 410.

The query is as follows.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from rpush_notifications where error_code = 410").find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000)
```

But it is returning the following error **undefined method `find_in_batches' for #<PG::Result**

1. Any idea on how to fix this?
2. Can we do this in the ActiveRecord way? something like `RpushNotification.where(error_code: 410).find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000)`
   The issue here is that, there is no RpushNotification model associated with it.
3. Is there any issue if i create a model file rpush_notification.rb?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's an `ActiveRecord` method. `execute` returns an `PG::Result`. I think that creating a model file `rpush_notification.rb` may work, but you can try to make sure.

Comment: if you are using `rpush` gem then `rpush` gem should have `Notification` class which you can use to fetch result in ActiveRecord way.